# how to increase div size in navbar dropdown menu in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a navbar dropdown using Bootstrap 4.  But in my one of menu item I want to customize downdown menu items using my own code. When I tried this I'm not able to increase the width of dropdown menu content. on click of dropdown-link it should show content properly.

Here below is the code.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white text-black">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" style="border:none;outline:0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">T1</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="">
                                            <label label-default="" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label label-default="" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> T2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">t3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'm expecting below output.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to increase the width?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `min-width` in the `.dropdown-menu` class.

EDIT for example:

```
.dropdown-menu {min-width: 30rem;}
```